# ¿Cómo cambio la apariencia de un botón HTML y copio al portapeles (Clipboardjs.com)?

Tags: html, css, interfaz-gráfica

El problema que tengo es que quiero hacer un botón de copiar un texto al portapapeles en mi página web, pero el botón aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo quiero que se vea algo tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(al pasar el mouse por encima cambia de color a un tono celeste clarito)

El código HTML que estoy usando es el de [Clipboardjs.com](https://clipboardjs.com/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>target-div</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- 1. Define some markup -->
    <div>hello</div>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="div">Copy</button>

    <!-- 2. Include library -->
    <script src="../dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

    <!-- 3. Instantiate clipboard -->
    <script>
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que alguien sepa la solución. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué la imagen de la pregunta es de publicidad?¿Tienes alguna relación con el sitio que se especifica en la imagen? Casi parece spam

Comment: Hola. Tiene una pequeña publicidad porque justamente quiero hacer lo que hace esa web (magicraft.es), lo que yo quiero es usar eso con otro texto. No se relaciona con spam, si ha parecido spam, esa no era mi intención. Saludos

Comment: Sigo sin entender por qué una imagen (y un comentario) con publicidad de un sitio externo. No tiene sentido y no aporta nada positivo a la pregunta. Sería mejor usar una imagen neutra.

Comment: No entiendo en qué te fastidia, porque ni si quiera tiene que ver con publicidad. Es de un servidor de Minecraft ese dominio. Y en ningún momento menciono nada al respecto.

Comment: ¿Cómo no tiene que ver con publicidad? Es una imagen que hace referencia innecesaria a otro sitio (publicidad), y tú mismo admitiste en el primer comentario que era "una pequeña publicidad". Pero vamos, quizás yo estoy siendo muy estricto, la cosa es que no veo la necesidad de añadir ese contenido a la pregunta. Cualquier otra imagen sin publicidad habría servido igual para el propósito de tu pregunta

Comment: Puede ser que sea innecesario, pero hice de esa imágen porque en esa web hace lo que yo buscaba. Pido disculpas por el malentendido. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí tienes un botón con un estilo y tu IP.

Simplemente pega esto en el editor HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.13/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="mc.bladecraftsv.net" style="
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #eb374b;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 20px;
"><div>mc.bladecraftsv.net</div><div style="
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
">Click para copiar</div></button>
```

Comment: Eso me funcionó perfecto genioooo. Love U Cesar Moro :v. !Cambio y corto!

Answer (score 2):

Añade la imagen y redimensiona el botón aplicándole un estilo de esta forma:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.13/clipboard.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="mc.bladecraftsv.net" style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4YJo.png');width:240px;height:49px;"></button>
    <script>var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Aunque es mejor tener los estilos separados como dice @Cig.
He añadido también la funcionalidad que pides de Clipboardjs.com.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48322/discussion-on-answer-by-awes0mem4n-como-cambio-la-apariencia-de-un-boton-html-y).

Comment: Por favor usa la sala de chat creada, no agregues más comentarios.

Comment: Se puede entrar al chat desde 20 y ya los tiene.

Answer (score 1):

Para eso basta con css puedes usar una hoja css aparte o directamente desde el HTML mediante las etiquetas `<style type="text/css"></style>` dentro de las etiquetas `<head></head>` de tu documento y el javascript dentro de las etiquetas `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

```js
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

```css
 .botonimagen{
          background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4YJo.png');
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
          height:49px;
          width:240px;
          background-position:center;

        }
        .botonimagen:hover{
          opacity: .9;
        }
        .hidden{display:none;}
```

```html
<textarea class="js-copytextarea hidden">mc.bladecraftsv.net</textarea>
<button class="btn botonimagen"></button>
```

Comment: Hola. Gracias por responder.
 ¿Pero cómo inserto ese código CSS junto con el código del botón?
Saludos

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta @Nerraden

Comment: No acabo entendiendo. Soy novato en esto. Me explicarías cómo insertarlo y que quede bien? Digamos, yo inserté el código que pusiste en mi web en la parte de HTML utilizando los <style> pero no aparece ningún botón.

Comment: @Nerraden volvi a editar la respuesta para ahora hagas el clipboard, sin ocupar esa libreria xD

Comment: Sigo sin entender dónde poner el código xD. Digamos, yo tengo 4 secciones, editor como texto normal, como HTML, como CSS y como JavaScript, vos me pasaste 3 códigos en secciones separadas, pegué los 2 primeros códigos en la parte de CSS y el último en la de HTML. Hice bien? Porque no quedó ningún botón, nada más un recuadro para escribir que dice "Algo para copiar".

Comment: @Nerraden El primer codigo va entre las etiquetas <script></script> y esto a su ves dentro de las etiquetas <head></head>, despues el siguiente es dentro de las etiquetas <style></style> y esto tambien dentro de las etiquetas <head></head> y el ultimo va dentro de etiquetas <body></body>, por ende si tienes esas secciones el primer codigo va dentro de tu bloque javascript, el segundo dentro de CSS y el ultimo de HTML